# Regular expression with symbol between number

Tags: c#, regex

**Situation**

I am trying to build a string `2010/2011` basically a year range in that format.

**What have i done**

I have the expression `^((?=.{4,4}$)[0-9]+$)` where it accepts 4 numbers
I can change this to `^((?=.{8,8}$)[0-9]+$)` and it will accept 8 numbers.However, I have still not solved the problem of getting my `/` between the two years.
I attempted `^((?=.{4,4}$)[0-9]+$).` where I expect to be able to enter 2010z(four numbers plus any) however it still throws an error.

So my questions, can I specifically state an expression like`{4 digits}{ONLY /}{4 digits`. If so, how do I combine `^((?=.{4,4}$)[0-9]+$)` and only allow '/' between them.

Comment: Well, maybe you just need [`\A[0-9]{4}(?:/[0-9]{4})?\z`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cA%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%28%3f%3a%2f%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%29%3f%5cz&i=2010%2f2011)?

Comment: Note that `^((?=.{4,4}$)[0-9]+$)` = `^([0-9]{4}$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works in the editor you link but testing it in http://regexr.com/ gives an error.

Comment: @Niana My regex works in C# code, and I guess it is the only thing that matters here. Do not test a .NET regex at a Web regex tester that does not support .NET regex syntax. You must test the regex with a compatible regex tester. Or in your target environment. In .NET, `\d` matches more than `0-9` ASCII digits by default, and `$` does not ensure the match at the end of the string. The answers below with `\d` and `$` are OK, but may be not precise. In .NET regex, there is no need escaping `/`, either.

Comment: Well, could you please show your code? I see you are in doubt what to use.

Comment: There are different flavors of regex parsers. The javascript regex parser is different from C# (really .Net's) regex parser. Hence one will get different results with the same data, same pattern from different parsers!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly you would want something like:

```
^(\d{4})\?(\d{4})?$
```

Meaning 4 digits come in followed by an optional slash 4 digits.

Comment: Why use not capturing matches for the years, if at all?

Comment: Oh, you can use capturing if you wish.  But I've felt it's good practice to only capture (thus storing in memory) the results if I'm going to use them later.  You can certainly just use it without the ?:  I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Capturing is simply the act of putting things into groups outside of the main match of `.Groups[0]`. By using `(?: )` you tell the parser to **match** what is in the parenthesis but not to put it into its own group such as `group[1..n]` capture. I don't know what you mean by "storing in memory".

Comment: If you look at my example, I use capturing groups `( )` and it creates match capture groups of 0, 1 and 2. If I used match, but don't capture of `(?: )` like `^(?:\d{4})[^\d]?(?:\d{4})$` instead, I would not have groups of 1 and 2; only the full match of group 0.

Comment: ah, I see.  I didn't know you wanted to capture the results.  What I meant by stored in memory is when you have very large capture groups, at least from my experience, it seems to hinder performance as it stores of the results for later use.  Like stuffing a 1 gig file into a string will use 1 gig of ram.   But that's when you are capturing huge amounts of data.  Not so in this case!  Answer updated.

Comment: @Niana if you found this answer helpful it would be great if you could accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex: `(?=.{4,4}$)` actually means:

- Forward lookup,
- for 4 **arbitrary** characters (not numbers),
- and then the end of string.

So whatever is after it, it will not match a string like `2010/2011`.

Try "more natural" regex:

```
^(\d{4})\/(\d{4})$
```

It means:

- start of string,
- four digits (1st capturing group),
- a slash (quoted),
- another four digits (2nd capturing group),
- end of string.

I used capturing groups, because I thought you could be interested in both
numbers (before and after the slash), so it will be easier to read them just
from the capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one which takes any separator character or no separator character and ensures that each year is four numbers or no match exists.

So `2010-2017` works as well as `2010/2017` or `2010 2017` or `20102017` but not `201092017`.

`^\d{4}[^\d]?\d{4}$`

If you need to capture the individual years use `( )` to make groups so the pattern now looks like this

`^(\d{4})[^\d]?(\d{4})$`

and extract at `myMatch.Groups[1].Value` and `myMatch.Groups[2].Value`.

---

Result on `2010/2017` is this match with these `Groups[X]`

```
Match #0
          [0]:  2010/2017
  ["1"] → [1]:  2010
  ["2"] → [2]:  2017
```